# How to set up listener to salesforce outbound message in java using maven?

Tags: soap-api, integration, webservices, java, workflowoutboundmessage

I am trying to set up salesforce outbound messaging listener in java. This is the link I followed to set up, and it works fine - https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Creating_an_Outbound_Messaging_Notification_Service_with_Eclipse_3.2

The article was unfortunately never updated after 2012, and I want to set this up as a maven project for obvious reasons -this is where I run into difficulties.

I am looking for the right maven plugin to basically reproduce whatever was in the link.The idea is that, I need to have an endpoint listener, such that it can receive a soap message from salesforce. With me right now, I have a wsdl file (that I get from salesforce), and this is my starting point. The endpoint is also included in the wsdl. From a lot of research, I decided to use the apache cxf maven plugin to generate the classes from wsdl. I also have a public endpoint available to receive the message.

However I am stuck and unsure as to how to to proceed from here. Once I get the classes, how do I configure the endpoint listener? From the generated classes, there is one interface NotificationPort , which has the method that is called when a message hits the endpoint. I know that I need to have a class that implements the interface. How do I run and test the service from now?

This is my pom.xml

```
      <properties>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
<cxf.version>3.1.11</cxf.version>
    <wsdl.generated.sources>${basedir}/src/main/java</wsdl.generated.sources>
<wsdl.location>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/META-INF/supplyorder.wsdl</wsdl.location>
</properties>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
</dependency>

      </dependencies>  
    <build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>generate-sources</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceRoot>${wsdl.generated.sources}</sourceRoot>
                    <wsdlOptions>
                        <wsdlOption>
                            <wsdl>${wsdl.location}</wsdl>
                        </wsdlOption>
                    </wsdlOptions>
                </configuration>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

wsdl relevant parts

```
    <!-- Binding 
 You need to write a service that implements this binding to receive the notifications -->
    <binding name="NotificationBinding" type="tns:NotificationPort">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="notifications">
    <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
    <input>
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </input>
    <output> 
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
    </output>
</operation>
 </binding>
   <!-- Service Endpoint -->
  <service name="NotificationService">
  <documentation>Notification Service Implementation</documentation>
  <port binding="tns:NotificationBinding" name="Notification">
      <soap:address 
     location="http://localhost:8080/SupplyOrder/Notification"/>
   </port>
   </service>
```

Questions: 1. I wrote a custom class that implements the interface NotificationsPort. How do I run and test this web service? What can I use as run time environment to run it? Would tomcat work?

Is there anyway I can use Spring to get this set up? -as I would highly prefer to use that.